# How to send response back to initiator

Tags: python-3.x, quickfix, fix-protocol

so i am trying to set up a FIX server that will serve me to accept FIX messages.
i managed to receive messages from a demo client that i made.
i want to perform an action according to the received message and then return a response to the initiator.

i have added the code that i use, it somehow sends it through the acceptor back to the initiator.

```py
import quickfix as fix


def create_fix_response_for_wm(self, session_id, message, api_response):
        try:
            report = quickfix50sp2.ExecutionReport()
            report.setField(fix.Text(api_response.text))
            report.setField(fix.ListID(message.getField(66)))
            if message.getFieldIfSet(fix.OrderID()):
                report.setField(fix.OrderID(message.getField(14)))
            elif message.getFieldIfSet(fix.ListID()):
                report.setField(fix.OrderID(message.getField(66)))


            fix.Session.sendToTarget(report, session_id)
        except Exception as e:
            logger.exception(f'could not create response')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so after looking and testing a couple of times this is what i found.

```
import quickfix as fix

def create_fix_response_for_wm(self, session_id, message, api_response):
        try:
            report = quickfix50sp2.ExecutionReport()
            report.setField(fix.Text(api_response.text))
            report.setField(fix.ListID(message.getField(66)))
            if message.getFieldIfSet(fix.OrderID()):
                report.setField(fix.OrderID(message.getField(14)))
            elif message.getFieldIfSet(fix.ListID()):
                report.setField(fix.OrderID(message.getField(66)))


            fix.Session.sendToTarget(report, session_id)
        except Exception as e:
            logger.exception(f'could not create response')
```

session_id = should be a SessionID object which can be built like this:

`session_id = fix.SessionID("FIXT.1.1", <ACCEPTOR - SenderCompID of the acceptor configuration>, <INITIATOR - TargetCompID in the acceptor configuration >)`

configuration example:

```
[SESSION]
SocketAcceptPort=12000
StartDay=sunday
EndDay=friday
AppDataDictionary=./glossary/FIX50SP2.xml
TransportDataDictionary=./glossary/FIXT11.xml
DefaultApplVerID=FIX.5.0SP2
BeginString=FIXT.1.1
SenderCompID=MYACCEPTOR
TargetCompID=CLIENT
```

`session_id = fix.SessionID("FIXT.1.1","MYACCEPTOR" , "CLIENT")` - in our case

you you this sessionID object when sending.

`fix.Session.sendToTarget(<YOUR MESSAGE>, session_id)`